# How to set scons to output full expanded command line?

Tags: c++, macos, scons

I've come across a build system that uses scons. Not being familiar at all with scons itself being a rather sophisticated framework I get very frustrated not being able to debug build issues.

**I want scons to printout the fully expanded command line being invoke ( as you see with most build systems)** I found out you could use the **--debug=presub** option but ( at least on OSX ) it is useless since it prints the value of unexpanded variables

for example:

```
Building build/obj/ios-uni-rel-sta-clang/common/libs/boost/libs/date_time/src/gregorian/date_generators.i386.o with action:
  $SHCXX -o $TARGET -c $SHCXXFLAGS $SHCCFLAGS $_CCCOMCOM $SOURCES
```

There is also a **VERBOSE=1** parameter you can supply on the scons command line but ( at least with the 2.3.4 ) version I got, it doesn't seem to be verbose much anything.

I'm not saying Scons is bad, but it is become a bit taxing and expansive to maintain :(

Anyone familiar with Scons? What module, where is the actual command gets invoked? I just want to add a few prints ...

Alternatively, how can you setup PyDev or PyCharm to hook up using the scons **--debug=pdb**? Did anyone this?

Comment: Can you show what the actual output is now? Also what package are you trying to build?  SCons allows the build system developers to hide the full output.

Comment: Is it using a patched scons? I have 2.3.4 on windows and it prints out the full command line in all its sordid detail

Comment: I am using 2.4.0, I ended up command-line-python-debugging Scons and added 'print "cmd = " + str(env.subs(cmd))' statement between line 827 and 828 of the Action.py module  to print out expanded command line.

Answer (score 6):

Somewhere in a SConstruct, SConscript, or some python module loaded by either (could be in site_scons under top dir) someone is changing the *COMSTR env variables.

It will look something like:

```
env['SHCXXCOMSTR'] = "Building $TARGET"
```

or:

```
for k in env.keys():
    if k.endswith('COMSTR'):
        env[k] = "Building $TARGET"
```

You'll want to comment out those lines.

The default SCons behavior is to show the command lines.

http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html#cv-SHCXXCOMSTR

Answer (score -3):

SHOWBUILD=1

For example: 
$>scons SHOWBUILD=1

This worked for me

Comment: SHOWBUILD is not scons default, but must be implemented in some sconstruct/sconscripts.