# Scons environment seems to be clobbered after adding static library

Tags: c++, scons, godot4, llamacpp

I'm building a [Godot extension](https://github.com/opyate/godot-llm-experiment), and here is my Scons file at commit [8907014](https://github.com/opyate/godot-llm-experiment/tree/89070142f02afffa9b8e08974e4c8afa15d68f54):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

env = SConscript("godot-cpp/SConstruct")

# For reference:
# - CCFLAGS are compilation flags shared between C and C++
# - CFLAGS are for C-specific compilation flags
# - CXXFLAGS are for C++-specific compilation flags
# - CPPFLAGS are for pre-processor flags
# - CPPDEFINES are for pre-processor defines
# - LINKFLAGS are for linking flags

llamacpp_path = ARGUMENTS.get('llamacpp_path', 'llama.cpp')  # llama.cpp is a directory, not a cpp file :)

# Specify where to find headers and libraries
env.Append(CPPPATH=[
    "src/",
    llamacpp_path,
    os.path.join(llamacpp_path, 'common'),
    # "godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/classes/"  # Add this path for wrapped.hpp
])
sources = Glob("src/*.cpp")

# Include wrapped.cpp in your sources
# sources.append("godot-cpp/src/classes/wrapped.cpp")

# add 'pthread' to libraries
libraries = ['pthread']
env.Append(LIBS=libraries)

# Object files from the specified path
object_files = [
    os.path.join(llamacpp_path, 'ggml-alloc.o'),
    os.path.join(llamacpp_path, 'k_quants.o'),
    os.path.join(llamacpp_path, 'ggml.o'),
    os.path.join(llamacpp_path, 'common.o'),
    os.path.join(llamacpp_path, 'llama.o')
]

# Create a static library from the object files
static_lib = env.StaticLibrary('llama', object_files)

# Link the shared library against the static library
if env["platform"] == "macos":
    library = env.SharedLibrary(
        "the-game/bin/libgdllm.{}.{}.framework/libgdllm.{}.{}".format(
            env["platform"], env["target"], env["platform"], env["target"]
        ),
        source=sources,
        LIBS=[static_lib]
    )
else:
    library = env.SharedLibrary(
        "the-game/bin/libgdllm{}{}".format(env["suffix"], env["SHLIBSUFFIX"]),
        source=sources,
        LIBS=[static_lib]
    )

Default(library)
```

When the GDExtension loads in the engine, it errors with undefined godot-cpp symbols. This worked previously before I added the llama static library:

```
static_lib = env.StaticLibrary('llama', object_files)
```

Without the llama static library, I got undefined llama symbols.

I'm new to Scons, so to my eyes it looks like that adding the llama static library broke the godot-cpp environment.

Given that llama and godot-cpp don't depend on each other, it's not a linking **order** issue.

[I also tried](https://github.com/opyate/godot-llm-experiment/blob/529b98c1891c64d76994603ff17edd45ef9d0bf8/SConstruct) to give godot-cpp and llama separate environments, but I'm still getting undefined godot-cpp symbols after that.

To recap:

- I got the [basic GDExtension example](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/gdextension/gdextension_cpp_example.html) working
- Then I added llama as a dependency, but got undefined llama symbols at runtime
- I changed llama to be a static library, but now get undefined godot-cpp symbols at runtime
- I fixed the first godot-cpp undefined symbol by adding the lines for wrapped.hpp and wrapped.cpp (now commented), but then it just moves onto the next undefined godot-cpp symbol. Is this the way to go? But, then, what is the point of the godot-cpp SConscript environment?

Comment: My guess would be that adding the static library simply fixes one problem allowing the build to proceed further until it encounters the next one, adding the static library isn't in itself causing the problem

Comment: @AlanBirtles I thought so too, but the godot-cpp definitions in the SConstruct file is exactly how it is in the basic example I got working, so somehow the addition of the llama static library messes up the environment. I'm looking into a way to compile the llama sources along with godot-cpp, instead of trying to link it in.

Comment: I got it working: https://github.com/opyate/godot-llm-experiment/blob/main/docs/it_works.png I clearly lack an understanding of scons, c/c++ build pipelines, etc, but here we are 

Comment: If you suspect that adding a static library changes compilation/linkage of the shared one, then you can easy check that by looking to the command lines which calls linker/compiler: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32799883/how-to-set-scons-to-output-full-expanded-command-line. In any case, without the **exact error message** we cannot help you to fix that error.

Comment: If you've solved your problem you should post how you solved it as an answer

Comment: @AlanBirtles nah, I just got it to work, I didn't solve the problem  https://www.reddit.com/r/GetMotivated/comments/h0xyzj/image_if_you_dont_know_how_to_use_them_it_will/

Answer (score 0):

Trimming away, you've done this:

```py
    library = env.SharedLibrary(
        "the-game/bin/libgdllm{}{}".format(env["suffix"], env["SHLIBSUFFIX"]),
        source=sources,
        LIBS=[static_lib]
    )
```

Passing keyword arguments to a builder creates what SCons calls an "override environment" - like an overlay - values are pulled from the override in preference to the base environment. In the override, you've set `LIBS` to a list containing just `static_lib`, meaning that build doesn't see any original value of `LIBS` - in other words, you're covering up whatever the call to `SConscript("godot-cpp/SConstruct")` set up for `env["LIBS"]` (which you then appended `pthread` to). You need to *add* your library (static or shared should make no difference), which is a little tricky. One approach might be to fetch it beforehand, something like:

```py
shliblist = env['LIBS'] + [static_lib]
library = env.SharedLibrary(... LIBS=shliblist ...)
```

or, if you think it won't hurt anything else, you can just `env.Append` like you did for the addition of `pthread`.

Additional comments:

```py
# llama.cpp is a directory, not a cpp file :)
```

Really recommend you don't do that... the chance of SCons (or someome else) misinterpreting that exists - the fact you need that comment at all is a hint.

```py
# Specify where to find headers and libraries
env.Append(CPPPATH=[   ...
```

`CPPPATH` is just for headers. If you want to set library search paths, you need to use `LIBPATH` (see https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html#cv-LIBPATH)

Comment: Brilliant, this is the kind of insight I was looking for. Will experiment with a fix later 